# adding custom page's link in homepage in opencart

Tags: opencart

I am new in **opencart**, and I am trying to build a new eCommerce site using opencart where I need to add some custom static page ( some additional page ). So I follow the link [New Page For OpenCart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775746/new-page-for-opencart) and [opencart php custom page without using the "information" feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490723/opencart-php-custom-page-without-using-the-information-feature), and I can create a new custom page. But my problem is, how can I get this page's link on my home and others page so that people view my page.

Comment: I don't think this question is on-topic here. You may want to try http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77558/opencart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating your link would depend greatly on how the page has been created, and where it's located.

Urls are built based on the location ie: route of your controller.

Let's say your new page has been built in:

`catalog/controller/common/mypage.php`

Obviously you'll need to follow the code standards listed in the posts you referenced for created a correct class that extends the Controller, a language file, a model class (if your page needs to interact with the database) and a view file.

Once all that is correct via the previous posts you can create a link anywhere on the catalog (front) by calling the url class and passing in the required information.

You'll need to pass in a route, any arguments such as an id or customer, and whether the url should be secure.

```
$link = $this->url->link('common/mypage', 'mypage_id=' . $this->request->get['mypage_id'], 'SSL');
```

$arguments and 'SSL' being optional if they're needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating a new page that way, you will be to access the page (called "newpage" for example) at: `/index.php?route=common/newpage` or `/index.php?route=common/home/newpage`   depending how you set it up.

The simplest way of creating a new page is to create a new information page. You can input your custom html there if needs be. The link would then look like:

`/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=x` where the id is the id of your new page.

To add this link into your main menu you can edit `template/common/header.tpl` and hardcode in the new link.